# Must you have a github account to set up a private git on your OWN server?

Tags: git, github

I wish to set up my own PRIVATE version control system using Git (not open source) for my own software project and I read a few tutorials (like https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-git-and-github-on-ubuntu/) and seems like they said about creating accounts on GitHub and linking to my own Git server?

Is that necessary?

Answer (score 2):

No. The tutorial is wrong.

You do always have to configure `user.name` and `user.email` with your information. But these settings have nothing to do with accounts on external websites; they do not store GitHub-specific information, do not control repository access, and are not used in push/fetch operations at all.

Instead, they describe the *person* making the Git commits – each commit has its "author" information filled in from these settings, and `user.name` is actually supposed to be your real name (as you would sign email messages with), not an account name.

Basically, your commits will just have *"Author: User Name <user@email>"* attached to them, and the information stored there is entirely up to you.

---

The only *indirect* relationship is that hosting websites will automatically link to the corresponding profile if they find a matching email address. For example, I've made two test commits and uploaded them to GitHub – both are signed with my real name, but one uses the same user.email as my GitHub account and becomes a clickable link to my GitHub account page; while the other uses a random email address and remains just plain text.

[image: (GitHub commit log showing two Git commits by the same person, but with different email addresses. One of them matches a GitHub account, the other doesn't.)]

However, the difference is purely visual on the website (and only matters for websites uploaded to GitHub in the first place, which you said you don't plan to do), and does not affect local Git operation in any way.

---

Note that there is nothing preventing you from hosting non-open-source software on GitHub/GitLab/BitBucket: they all offer private repositories (although not always for free), and they do not enforce any particular license on public repositories.